# What happens if method A calls method B and both have [Transaction] attribute?

Tags: c#, spring, attributes

I have a method say LogErrorA with [Transaction] attribute from Spring.Net and I want to call another method in it (say LogErrorB) which also has the [Transaction] attribute because I sometimes I need to call it directly. The LogErrorA call will work under one transaction in Spring.NET or multiple transactions will be created?

```
[Transaction]
public virtual void LogErrorA()

[Transaction]
public virtual void LogErrorB()
```

And LogErrorA calls inside LogErrorB.

Also, LogErrorB can be called directly some times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some predefined propagation methods for transaction like : Propagation.REQUIRED, Propagation.NEW, Propagation.NESTED and few more. But if you are not defining any propagation method that means it takes `Propagation.REQUIRED` by default.

Propagation.REQUIRED says that : If any transaction is not running then it will create new transaction and if any transaction exists at that particular point then it will use that existing transaction.

So in your case when you will call LogErrorB() from LogErrorA(), in that case it will not create new transaction but it will use same transaction that was created at LogErrorA() method.

If you still have any doubt please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Your answer gave me great information. So, I will use the "[Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Required)]". But I think that this is the default so I do not have to do anything else. I should just leave the attributes. Right?

Comment: It seems that is the default according to this page: http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-P3/reference/html/transaction.html. Please, let me know if I forget something..

Comment: Yes, `Propagation.Required` is default attribute value so you can leave attributes and it will consider it as Transaction.Required. For more on transaction you can refer this document as well : 

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html